# Setting Letter Size in FPDF

Tags: fpdf

I want to set my FPDF paper size to **8.5 X 13** that almost the same with MS Office Word paper size. Right now I' using the following codes below.

```
$pdf= new PDF('P','mm','A4');
```

How could I set my paper size the same with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use **millimeter**. You just need to convert 8.5 x 13 inch into millimeter.

You can also open MS Office Word, open **word options** then click on **advanced**. Then **change the measurement unit** to millimeters to see the millimeter size of the paper in MS office Word then use the size in the measurement of the  following paper sizes.

```
$pdf= new PDF('P','mm',array(215.9,279.4));
```

Answer (score 0):

The fpdf [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm) shows that you need an `array()` to set custom dimensions:

```
$pdf = new PDF('P','in',array(8.5,13))
```